# Load multiple Keras models in different processes

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have several trained Keras models, weights stored in h5 files using `keras.models.save_model`. They do not have the same architecture.

My goal is to load all of them in separate processes and be able to predict. I currently try doing this using a class which stores a TensorFlow session and graph object. I then use `with` statements at loading time and prediction time to prevent interference with any global variables.

I can create my (empty) Keras Sequential model without problems, but when I call its `load_weights` function, the process just freezes.

Setups with Graph and Session objects I tried:

- specific Graph and Session -> process freezes on load_weights
- specific Graph only -> "TypeError: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor"
- specific Session only -> process freezes on load_weights

I have been through most of the related answers on SO but have not been able to find a solution or even someone with the same problem.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This could  mean that your machine is out of memory.

Comment: @Mitiku According to htop, I still have 5 GB left. Also my models are 3,2 MB and for now I'm just trying to load two.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know the exact cause of the problem. However, I found out that my main process was loading a keras model and removing that solved my problem. I can now have multiple models running in parallel.